# Setting row data with when clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Having some trouble setting row data with a when clause in MySQL database.
Here is what I have:

```
use bank;
select b.branch_id, b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip,
Case
when b.state != 'MA' then b.address = 'Out of State'
end address
from branch b
;
```

The idea is to get all the information from a table called "branch", if the state column of branch has "MA" in it, the row should say "Out of state" for that column. However, what I have here does not work properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want the `case` statement instead of the `address` column.  In that case:

```
select b.branch_id, b.name,
       (case when b.state = 'MA' then b.address else 'Out of State' end) as address,
       b.city, b.state, b.zip,
from branch b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an `else` clause in the case expression.

```
Select 
    b.branch_id, 
    b.name, 
    Case when b.state = 'MA' then 'Out of State' else b.address end as address, 
    b.city, 
    b.state, 
    b.zip
from branch b
```

This will set the address column to 'Out of State' for all rows where state = 'MA'. Maybe you want it the other way around, if so just negate the condition.